# Regex in JS: How to match a string that starts with "api" with exceptions

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match all string that starts with `/api/v` except those ends with `/user/logout`.

Ex:

- /api/v2/segments (match)
- /api/v2/user (match)
- /api/v2/user/logout (NO match)

I'm trying with this regex but it doesn't work

```
/.*\/api\/v.*(^\/user\/logout)$/
```

Comment: Replace the first `.*` with `^`, remove the other one, use `/^\/api\/v(?!.*\/user\/logout$).*/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew like this `^\/api\/v(^\/user\/logout)$` ? Doesn't wotk

Comment: No, the second `^` will invalidate the pattern. You cannot match start of string in the middle of some text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\/api\/v(?!.*\/user\/logout$).*/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YdSXYW/1/)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/api\/v` - a `/api/v` string
- `(?!.*\/user\/logout$)` - (a negative lookahead) no 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, followed with `/user/logout` at the end of string are allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as many as possible.

You need no `.*` at the end if  you just test the string with `RegExp#test` for a match. If you want to use the match value, you need `.*` at the end.